# Why does autocomplete in Open Office Calc not work for older entries?

Tags: openoffice, autocomplete, openoffice-calc

I have a number of words in a Calc column that I update occasionally. When I type a new word in a cell, it will autocomplete if I already have one higher up in the column. This is useful so I don't make duplicate entries.

However, this doesn't work for older entries (words that I've entered a longer time ago). How can I make it check the entire column, including old words?

Comment: So you should close this question.

Comment: Post your findings as to why it can't as an answer itself. Then accept it a couple of days later. No need to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Update from author of question, moved from question to this answer:

> I've found that it only remembers the last 200 entries.